# collection find and mongoose find using different index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I meet a situation where using exactly same filter/sort to do the query, but when I run the query in robo mongo, it is hitting the correct index I want to. But with when running my application and do query using mongoose, it is hitting another index which should not.

E.g

```
db.getCollection('xxx').find({
   xxxId: ObjectId('xxxx'),
   xxxx: 'xxxxx',
   deleted: false,
}).sort({createdAt: -1});
```

This is hitting one index

```
xxxModel.find({
   xxxId: 'xxxx',
   xxxx: 'xxxxx',
   deleted: false,
}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Mongoose find is hitting a different index.

Any idea what might be the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first query

```
 xxxId: ObjectId('xxxx'),
```

would be matching the field `xxxId` with and ObjectId, while in the second query

```
`xxxId: 'xxxx',`
```

would be matching the field `xxxId` with the string `'xxxx'`.

These are different query shapes that might be best served by different indexes.

Comment: But since the second one is using mongoose, it passes string by itself, I get the query from Atlas, I can't even control what the query is. So how can I get mongoose to use the correct Index like the robo mongo ?

Comment: Add besides, those two search difference you list will return different results. But in my case both query return exactly same results